# Showing the keystrokes to enter mathematical symbols without converting to the symbol itself

Tags: formatting

In a Text cell I'd like to show readers the *keystrokes* to enter mathematical symbols, for instance **$\backslash$[Integral]**.  However, whenever I type those keystrokes, the interpreter converts the keystrokes into the symbol itself (destroying what I seek to show).

I've tried a number of techniques, such as `HoldForm`, `DisplayForm`, and so on, all without luck.

How do I display all the keystrokes without having them converted into the associated typographical symbol?

Comment: As a workaround, you could deliberately misspell `Integral` as `Integrals` and then finally remove the `s`.

Comment: I crtainly thoght f tht, buut thare *musst* bew a bettr wayy!

Comment: Maybe something like `Style[ToString[FullForm["∫"]]//StringTake[#,{2,-2}]&,ShowStringCharacters->False]`?

Comment: Yep!  That's it!  Post as an Answer and I'll accept.  (So much work for such a "simple" problem!)

Comment: Does `ToString["\[Integral]",CharacterEncoding->"ASCII"]` do what you want?

Comment: @CarlWolf:  Thanks, but no.  Once I paste your text into the Text cell, it gets evaluated and converted into the sign.  (I don't quite understand all this.)

Comment: Just as a supplement of @Silvia's comment. You can get this at `guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters`, then press `Cell->Show Expression`. You'll see for example `Cell["\\Integral", "InlineCharacterName",
  ShowSpecialCharacters->False]`, then `Cell["\\[Integral]", "Output",
  ShowSpecialCharacters->False]//CellPrint` will print `\[Integral]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here might be a good place for the notorious `\[InvisibleSpace]`.

So this is what I type in the text cell:

This is my text cell, if you type \<kbd>Esc</kbd>is<kbd>Esc</kbd>[Integral], you will get \[Integral].

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oh... that's a nice solution too.  Thanks so much!  ($+1$)

Answer (score 6):

Enclose the symbol in double quotes to form a `String`, and type two backslashes. The backslash acts as an "escape" character; putting two together disables this and treats it as an ordinary character. For example, `"\\[Integral]"`:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This does not work for me at all on Windows V13.1.

Comment: @Somos It works, please see at the screenshot.

Comment: Yes, I see the screenshot. I see the `Out[1]=` cell and then what? When I copy and paste I just get back the `In[1]:=` string with the double backslash.

Comment: @Somos You should copy not the cell, but its contents. And then paste it in a `"Text"` cell. Then you reproduce the result on the screenshot.

Comment: There are some details you are leaving out. I still can't duplicate what you have.

Answer (score 5):

The character with code 8726 looks nearly the same as a backslash, but it will have not the same effect:

```
{FromCharacterCode[8726], FromCharacterCode[92]}
```

[image: (* {"[Backslash]", "\"} *)]

With this:

[image]

Comment: A good workaround ($+1$), but there *must* be a better way!

Answer (score 2):

We can get the underline full name with `FullForm`:

```
FullForm["∫"]
(* Out[]//FullForm = "\[Integral]" *)
```

Although the key option here is actually `ShowSpecialCharacters -> False`, so this works as well (and arguably cleaner):

```
StyleBox["∫", ShowStringCharacters -> False, ShowSpecialCharacters -> False] // RawBoxes
(* Out[]= \[Integral] *)
```

Maybe more conveniently, the same option can be used at cell level, so we can do something like this:

<sub>(Note to make this example rendered properly, style `"Key1"` from *...\FrontEnd\StyleSheets\Wolfram\Reference.nb* is required.)</sub>

```
Cell[TextData[{"To input "
                , Cell[BoxData[FormBox[SubscriptBox["∫", RowBox[{"∂", "Ω"}]], TraditionalForm]]]
                , ", we can type it as "
                , Cell["∫", ShowSpecialCharacters -> False]
                , " "
                , Cell[BoxData[TemplateBox[{"Ctrl", "_"}, "Key1"]]]
                , " "
                , Cell["∂Ω", ShowSpecialCharacters -> False]
                , " ."}]
        , "Text"] // CellPrint
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note:

1. `CellPrint` here is just to insure the example is reproducible, in practice we actually input the cell directly: <kbd>Alt + 7</kbd> to start a Text cell, <kbd>Ctrl + 9</kbd> to insert an inline cell, etc.
2. Once the cell with `ShowSpecialCharacters -> False` is inserted (might need to edit the *cell expression*), there will be no need to manually type full names like `\[Integral]`, we can just past in special characters like `∫` and they should be rendered in full form automatically.

Finally a side note: Most of the time I found inputting special characters with full name is cumbersome, I usually use their <kbd>Esc</kbd> quoted alias (if they exist), like `\[AliasDelimiter]int\[AliasDelimiter]` and `\[AliasDelimiter]pd\[AliasDelimiter]` give me `\[Integral]` and `\[PartialD]` as well.